# Performance on partial constructor initialization

Tags: python, performance, constructor

I constructed my class to parse a message which is a dictionary (probably derived from a JSON object), see [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/3rMiSDzb) for further information.
Since I will get many of this objects, and I don't want to process them all
I thought to skip some steps in the initialization method. So I wrote a conditional initialization class.
I put a `glance` flag, which if active will process only 3 of the 7 possible members.
I would like tho to keep the option to look at the arguments later on thus  I thought also to put a `opt` flag which will simply store the message for further processing.

```py
class CbkQuery:

    def __init__(self, query_msg, glance = False, opt = True):          
        #required arguments
        self.id = query_msg['id']
        self.person = Person(query_msg['from'])
        self.chat_instance = query_msg['chat_instance']

        if glance:
            pass
        else:
            self.query_msg = query_msg
            if opt:
                # optional arguments
                self.data = self.query_msg.get('data')
                self.message = self.query_msg.get('message')
                if self.message is not None:
                    self.message = Message(self.message)
                self.inline_message_id = self.query_msg.get('inline_message_id')
                self.game_short_name = self.query_msg.get('game_short_name')
```

Now since I did this gimmick for actually having a performance gain I decided to log the performance (is a custom logging class I made that uses `perf_counter()`, I anyway checked multiple times and the difference in times seems stable)

```
glance processing took: (glance flag True, opt flag False)
Elapsed time for subprocess: 00:00:01.749

store query, processing took: (glance flag False, opt flag False)
Elapsed time for subprocess: 00:00:00.182

build complete class processing took: (glance flag False, opt flag True
Elapsed time for subprocess: 00:00:01.322
```

'Surprise surprise, glancing the class takes longer then all the other (?!?!?), the fastest is to store the "unprocessed message in the class".
Can somebody explain me why? Is it because storing the unprocessed message actually makes a shallow copy instead of a copy?

Comment: I used the module time, and perf_counter, I know is not compelety accurate, yet theres a difference of 1 second, and I'm interested bottom down what is the time needed on my pc to do that operation, not the time that the operation potentially can have (like removing .sleep()) and such... (at least this was the reasoning of using perf instead of other more accurate measuring methods)

Comment: Oups, I wanted to ask whether you used the module `timeit`. It allows accurate timing of Python code because it automatically does a number of execution and computes an average value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the first test takes longer is beyond my comprehesion indeed (but your code would be much more readable with a negative test instead of a `pass` and `else` statements).

But why it's fastest to just "store the unprocessed message" is quite obvious: it's one single operation (storing a reference to `query_msg` in the instance's `__dict__`) instead of N times getting a value from `query_msg` and storing a reference to this value in the instance's `__dict__`.

This has nothing to do with deep or shallow copies - Python NEVER "copies" anything instead explicitely asked for -, in both cases it only stores references to objects.

As a side note if `query_msg` is a `dict` and your class is mostly a wrapper for it, you could just build your instance's `__dict__` from `query_msg`, ie:

```
def __init__(self, query_msg):
    self.__dict__.update(query_msg)
    self.person = Person(query_msg["from"])
    self.message = Message(self.message)
```

Or if you're ok to trade attribute access time for instanciation time, just keep a ref to `query_msg` and add properties to access it's values as attributes:

```
class CbkQuery(object):
    def __init__(self, query_msg):
        self._query_msg = query_msg

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._query_msg["id"]

    @property
    def chat_instance(self):
        return self._query_msg["chat_instance"]

    # etc

    @property
    def person(self):
       # here we cache the `Person` instanciation
       # to avoid repeating it on each and every access
       if not hasattr(self, "_person"):
           self._person = Person(self._query_msg["from"])
       return self._person

    # etc
```

wrt/ your benchmark I get very different results using `timeit` (with mock implementations for `Person` and `Message`):

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

class Message(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

class CbkQuery(object):
    def __init__(self, query_msg, glance=False, opt=True):          
        self.id = query_msg['id']
        self.person = Person(query_msg['from'])
        self.chat_instance = query_msg['chat_instance']

        if glance:
            pass
        else:
            self.query_msg = query_msg
            if opt:
                self.data = self.query_msg.get('data')
                self.message = self.query_msg.get('message')
                if self.message is not None:
                    self.message = Message(self.message)
                self.inline_message_id = self.query_msg.get('inline_message_id')
                self.game_short_name = self.query_msg.get('game_short_name')


qmsg = {
    "id":"id",
    "from":"test@example.com",
    "chat_instance":"chat_instance",
    "data":"data",
    "message":"message",
    'inline_message_id':'inline_message_id',
    "game_short_name":"game_short_name"
    }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit

    print("True, False: {}".format(timeit.timeit("CbkQuery(qmsg, True, False)", "from __main__ import CbkQuery, qmsg")))
    print("False, False: {}".format(timeit.timeit("CbkQuery(qmsg, False, False)", "from __main__ import CbkQuery, qmsg")))
    print("False, True: {}".format(timeit.timeit("CbkQuery(qmsg, False, True)", "from __main__ import CbkQuery, qmsg")))
```

Which yields the following results (with Python 2.7.6 and 3.4.3):

```
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground$ python whythefuck.py 
True, False: 0.732594013214
False, False: 0.785747051239
False, True: 1.89674901962


bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground$ python3 whythefuck.py 
True, False: 0.776961212977767
False, False: 0.8794295950210653
False, True: 1.832904842973221
```

Small differences between 2.7.x and 3.x but that's nonetheless much more consistent with what one would expect - the more instructions the code executes, the longer it takes ;)

I definitly think there's something borked with your tests...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Is actually one of the first times I extensively use dict in my code. I'm learning how to use the API that sends the message, so the fields are also some kind of memo of what they are, but I was looking for the `.update()` method and the `@propriety` decorator. What I don't understand is that all the three constructor do actually put some stuff in a new attribute... but it seems they get a boost if the whole input is stored. Might be some sort of optimiziation? Oh look this guy is making a wrapper -> let's use the original?

Comment: I can tell you that Python will never try and do any "optimization" of this kind. As I said, I can't understand the results you get from your benchmark and suspect some logical error somewhere in your testing code (something getting accidentaly cached or so - Python does have a few gotchas).

Comment: I also am quite puzzled. https://pastebin.com/YLhxEmHc here is the logger I wrote (I could have used `logging` but for some reason it didnt print stuff to the IPython console and I didnt wanted to look for configurations...

Comment: Did some benchmark with `timeit` and I get very different results, cf my edited answer.

Comment: thank you for testing it. I'll have to rethink on using time.perf_counter() while benchmarking, Courious tho.